# postgresql recursive category tree where are the children in the top parent's array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I reviewed many solutions and did not find a suitable example.

I have a certain selection

```
CREATE TABLE category
(
    uuid uuid not null primary key,
    name character varying(32),
    parent_uuid uuid references category(uuid),
);

INSERT INTO category
(uuid, name, parent_uuid) 
VALUES 
('8a70180b-3644-4b17-af5f-93cbe0090cce', 'Electronics', null),
('d9093660-241a-48f6-bf09-b6a8c6c7f12a', 'Microcontrollers', '8a70180b-3644-4b17-af5f-93cbe0090cce'),
('376ae1cb-425d-44d2-b19a-19b6f1e86314', 'Arduino, 'd9093660-241a-48f6-bf09-b6a8c6c7f12a'),
('5d5f174a-5c8e-4d12-912f-8173e255e35a', 'ESP8266', 'd9093660-241a-48f6-bf09-b6a8c6c7f12a'),
('f79f5fa0-6eaf-465b-9b14-e3b49c5ac9ef', 'Food', null),
('8aa95eda-7963-40ef-be44-076cdf06c5c1', 'Meat', 'f79f5fa0-6eaf-465b-9b14-e3b49c5ac9ef');
```

Ultimately I want to build a tree

1. Electronics

   - Microcontrollers

     - Arduino
     - ESP8266
2. Food

   - Meat

I managed to make a selection of parents

```
WITH RECURSIVE nodes(uuid, name, parents) AS (
    SELECT
        uuid,
        name,
        ARRAY[]::uuid[]
    FROM category
    WHERE parent_uuid IS null

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        category.uuid,
        category.name,
        parents || nodes.uuid
    FROM category
    JOIN nodes ON nodes.uuid = category.parent_uuid
)

SELECT * FROM nodes;
```

result:

| uuid | name | parents |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8a70180b-3644-4b17-af5f-93cbe0090cce | Electronics | {} |
| f79f5fa0-6eaf-465b-9b14-e3b49c5ac9ef | Food | {} |
| 8aa95eda-7963-40ef-be44-076cdf06c5c1 | Meat | {f79f5fa0-6eaf-465b-9b14-e3b49c5ac9ef} |
| d9093660-241a-48f6-bf09-b6a8c6c7f12a | Microcontrollers | {8a70180b-3644-4b17-af5f-93cbe0090cce} |
| 376ae1cb-425d-44d2-b19a-19b6f1e86314 | Arduino | {8a70180b-3644-4b17-af5f-93cbe0090cce, d9093660-241a-48f6-bf09-b6a8c6c7f12a} |
| 5d5f174a-5c8e-4d12-912f-8173e255e35a | ESP8266 | {8a70180b-3644-4b17-af5f-93cbe0090cce, d9093660-241a-48f6-bf09-b6a8c6c7f12a} |

However, this is not ideal for me. I would prefer this

| uuid | name | children |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8a70180b-3644-4b17-af5f-93cbe0090cce | Electronics | [{d9093660-241a-48f6-bf09-b6a8c6c7f12a, 376ae1cb-425d-44d2-b19a-19b6f1e86314}, {d9093660-241a-48f6-bf09-b6a8c6c7f12a, 5d5f174a-5c8e-4d12-912f-8173e255e35a}] |
| f79f5fa0-6eaf-465b-9b14-e3b49c5ac9ef | Food | [{8aa95eda-7963-40ef-be44-076cdf06c5c1}] |

I don't quite understand how to do it. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping the base/root uuid & name in the recursive loop can help for the aggregation.

The solution below uses an `EXISTS` to know when the recursion ended.

> ```
> WITH RECURSIVE RCTE_NODES AS (
>   SELECT
>     uuid
>   , name
>   , uuid as root_uuid
>   , name as root_name
>   , 1 as lvl
>   , ARRAY[]::uuid[] as children
>   , true as has_next
>   FROM category
>   WHERE parent_uuid IS null
>
>   UNION ALL
>
>   SELECT
>     cat.uuid
>   , cat.name
>   , cte.root_uuid
>   , cte.root_name
>   , cte.lvl+1
>   , cte.children || cat.uuid
>   , (exists(select 1 from category cat2 where cat2.parent_uuid = cat.uuid))
>   FROM RCTE_NODES cte
>   JOIN category cat
>     ON cat.parent_uuid = cte.uuid
> )
> SELECT root_uuid as uuid, root_name as name
> , array_agg(children) as children
> FROM RCTE_NODES
> WHERE has_next = false
> GROUP BY root_uuid, root_name
> ORDER BY root_uuid;
> ```

| uuid | name | children |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8a70180b-3644-4b17-af5f-93cbe0090cce | Electronics | {{d9093660-241a-48f6-bf09-b6a8c6c7f12a,376ae1cb-425d-44d2-b19a-19b6f1e86314},{d9093660-241a-48f6-bf09-b6a8c6c7f12a,5d5f174a-5c8e-4d12-912f-8173e255e35a}} |
| f79f5fa0-6eaf-465b-9b14-e3b49c5ac9ef | Food | {{8aa95eda-7963-40ef-be44-076cdf06c5c1}} |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=df45444b8196747865419cb8b6d259be)*